# Zorn's lemma, arbitrary cardinality

Tags: probability, analysis

Zorn's lemma states that a numerically ordered set in which each chain has an upper bound must have a maximum element.

But does a chain of arbitrary cardinality have an upper bound?

Comment: Most statements of Zorn's Lemma do not assume the partially ordered set is countable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma (Indeed, the proof in the countable case is "easier".)

Comment: @halrankard2: Most??? All.

Comment: What is a numerically ordered set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair enough

Comment: Also, in the countable case, the proof is not just easier, it requires no use of AC.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason for my quotes.

Answer (score 3):

> But does a chain of arbitrary cardinality have an upper bound?

**If** every chain in your partial order has an upper bound, **then** you can apply Zorn's lemma and conclude that there is a maximal element in your partial order. If there is even a single chain (of any cardinality) without an upper bound in your partial order, then Zorn's lemma doesn't tell us anything about that order.

Zorn's lemma says **nothing** about the existence of such chains. Just what happens if you find them.

There are plenty of examples where there exists uncountable chains with upper bounds. For instance, $P(\Bbb Q)$, the power set of the rational numbers, ordered by inclusion has an uncountable chain given by the Dedekind cuts: The subsets $U\subseteq \Bbb Q$ such that $p\in U, q<p$ implies $q\in U$ (plus a few other minor requirements that are unnecessary to this example). There are $|\Bbb R|$ such sets, and they are totally ordered, so that's an uncountable chain. $\Bbb Q$ itself is an upper bound for that chain.

Comment: +1 not so much for the answer but for understanding exactly the OP's difficulty.  You must be a very good Math instructor/professor!